# Unable to delete previous doSMP queues

Tags: r, multicore

I'm trying to use doSMP, and when I try `w <- startWorkers(4)`, I get the error

> 1: In startWorkers(workerCount = 4) :
>
> there is an existing doSMP session using doSMP1

(actually doSMP1,...doSMP8). Now, when I try to remove this using `rmSessions('doSMP1')` I get the error message

> attempting to delete qnames: doSMP1
>
> unable to delete queues: doSMP1

Any suggestions on how to get this to work. On my 8-core machine, doSNOW stopped working from version 2.11, and I would like to be able to parallel process locally without sending things out to a linux server.

I'm running R 2.12.1 (32-bit) on WinXP 64-bit on a 8-core machine.

Comment: You have to delete some files that are created in a temporary directory. I can't remember where from the top of my head right now, it's been ages since I've last used doSMP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

doSMP is actually developed to be used on the Revolution build, and is rather heavy on your system. In my experience it can crash R rather easily if you're not very, very careful about what you're doing. For parallel computing, I have far better experiences with the packages [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html), [snowfall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html) (which is essentially a front-end to snow) and [multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/index.html).

Also make sure that you use the latest version of R (2.12.2), as the current build of doSMP is compiled for 2.12.2.

If you really need to get rid of those sessions, you can try to delete the files in the temporary directory specified when looking at the workers object :

```
>  w <- startWorkers(workerCount = 4)
> w
$taskq
<pointer: 0x05974f20>

$qname
[1] "doSMP1"

$workerCount
[1] 4

$tmpdir
[1] "C:\\Users\\JORISF~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpXxLcTk\\doSMP44c815a1"
```

This directory you should clear. After you wrote down the temporary file, first stop the current workers and then try to delete all sessions :

```
stopWorkers(w)
rmSessions(all=TRUE)
```

Then clean out the directory. Then restart R. Sometimes it happens that after startup there is still a remainder of the sessions running, you'll see that if you use `startWorkers()` again. If so, again use first `stopWorkers(w)` without registering first! Then again do rmSessions(all=TRUE). Sometimes R will simply crash. Restart and continue as indicated here.

Finally, forget about doSMP and use one of the other mentioned packages. Snowfall will give you the least headaches if you have no previous experience. There's a nice introduction [here](http://www.informatik.uni-ulm.de/ni/staff/HKestler/Reisensburg2009/PDF/snowfall-tutorial.pdf).

**UPDATE : From R2.14 on you have the built-in package `parallel` that combines the functionality of `multicore` and `snow`.**